Cannot open an HTML file stored on RAM-disk with a browser
I wrote a script that generates a PDF and an HTML file on RAM-disk:

The PDF file can be opened as expected.
The HTML file can be opened with an editor, but not with a browser.

This is the error message I get from the browser (Chrome, Firefox) on Ubuntu Linux 24.04:
Access to the file was denied
The file at file:///dev/shm/test.html is not readable. It may have been removed, moved or file permissions may be preventing access.
ERR_ACCESS_DENIED

These are the file details:
/dev/shm> ll
-rw-rw-r-- 1  11K 2024-08-30 11:06 test.html

If I copy the file to the hard disk, it can be opened as expected:
/dev/shm> cp ./test.html ~


If I build Chromium from source as explained here, will I be able to open files stored on RAM-disk like /dev/shm?

Can the browser open any html file on /dev/shm? And what OS are you using?

Have you modified the output of ls -l? It usually includes the owner and group.

@Kusalananda - Yes, I have. Most of the times I do not need the user and group.

@terdon - I am using Ubuntu Linux 24.04.

@terdon - No, browsers cannot open any HTML file stored in /dev/shm.

Is the browser a snap?

@vidarlo - No, it is the default provided during Ubuntu installation.

Then it's probably a snap.

You can install the normal Firefox instead: How to Install Firefox as DEB on Ubuntu (Not Snap).

It's not that /dev/shm is of filesystem type tmpfs, but directly related to the snap installation. Evidence:
echo '<h1>Header</h1><p>Paragraph of text</p>' >/tmp/file.html
cp /tmp/file.html /dev/shm

firefox file:///tmp/file.html        # Firefox renders the file as expected

firefox file:///dev/shm/file.html    # Firefox fails to render, with permission denied
firefox file:///dev/shm              # Firefox renders the directory as expected

sudo umount /dev/shm                 # Remove the tmpfs filesystem
cp /tmp/file.html /dev/shm

firefox file:///dev/shm/file.html    # Firefox STILL fails to render, with permission denied

Furthermore
sudo mkdir /mnt/shm
sudo mount -t tmpfs /mnt/shm         # Mount a tmpfs filesystem elsewhere
cp /tmp/file.html /mnt/shm

firefox file:///mnt/shm/file.html    # Firefox renders as expected

Ubuntu 22.04 uses a "snap" version of Firefox as part of its standard installation, and such applications are sandboxed and prevented from accessing files in much of the filesystem (including those in /dev/shm but not the directory itself). Furthermore, the set of accessible directories is not configurable.

Relevant references

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388679/snap-applications-firefox-and-chromium-snap-cannot-open-folders-mounted-via-ss#comment2398571_1388679
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1184357/why-cant-chromium-suddenly-access-any-partition-except-for-home#comment1978874_1184357
https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/155txyp/snap_has_no_permission_to_access_devshm/
How to disable snap filesystem sandboxing
Yes, the list of mount points really is hardcoded


Yup. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1227963/how-to-disable-snap-filesystem-sandboxing tells how to disable sandboxing for an app. Strictly speaking this makes a lot of sense; the browser should not need to poke things in /dev normally.

@vidarlo thanks. I don't run Ubuntu (or snap) usually so this was an interesting exercise

I use the /dev/shm RAM-disk when I have to generate many temporary files, to avoid SSD wearing. I will see how to disable sandboxing for Chrome. Hopefully this will have no side effects...

What I would like to do is to add /dev/shm to the list of directories accessible by all snap based applications. Is there a way to do it?

Not possible, apparently

@vidarlo "the browser should not need to poke things in /dev normally" /dev/shm is a backing store for shared memory that any process may use. Certainly, chromium on my system uses it, as well as /dev/urandom and /dev/null. So I disagree with your statement there.
